# Is there a way to skip to a certain line in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am looking to find a way to skip to or goto the end if certain condition is not met. I'm just learning VBA code for a home project, very new at this. Here is what I have.

```vb
Sub Macro1()

    ' Some stuff here

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A8") <> "" Then
         GoTo Line122
    Else
        ' Do all this if the condition is false
    End If

    ' There is more in between

    ' I want to skip to here
    Call Test

End Sub

Sub Test()

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:08:00"), "Macro1"

End Sub
```

If Cell A8 is blank I want to wait 8 min then start `Macro1` with refresh. How can I skip the rest part of code after condition check and continue directly from the line `Call Test`?

Comment: is that line the first line after the `End If`?

Comment: FWIW you very, very, *very* likely DON'T want to `GoTo` anywhere.

Comment: No, there is more in between. The call test is near the end of the sub.

Comment: Is there something else to use insted of GoTo? like skip to?

Comment: If you have to jump around in a procedure, it is too long. Split it into smaller pieces that perform discrete tasks.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need this

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A8") <> "" Then
    Call Test
    Exit Sub
Else
    'Do all this if the condition is false
End If
```

Comment: @Chris, any feedback?

Comment: I used Kyrubas suggestion and its working like a charm. I may try yours also to get more familiar with VBA. Thanks for everyone's help!!

Comment: The more familiar you get with VBA, the more you want to avoid “GoTo”

Answer (score 0):

`GoTo` tells VBA to skip to a line label in your code rather than a specific line. For an additional example check out the [code at this bottom of this documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/goto-statement)

```
Sub MainSub()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A8") <> "" Then
        GoTo mytag
    Else
        'Do all this if the condition is false
    End If

    ' More code in here

mytag:
    Call test

End Sub


Sub test()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:08:00"), "Macro1"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code with functionality you need may look like this:

```vb
Sub Macro1()

    ' Some stuff here

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    If Not Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A8") <> "" Then
        ' Do all this if the condition is false
        ' There is more in between
    End If

    ' I want to skip to here
    Call Test

End Sub

Sub Test()

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:08:00"), "Macro1"

End Sub
```

Comment: Why the double negative

Comment: @urdearboy That is just to keep original condition `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A8") <> ""` untouched for clarity.